# Keyframe Animations with Styled Components in V4

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to simply animate a div to change background colors to replicate a success flash, but having trouble with styled components keyframes and css helpers.

An example of the code is below, I've also tried not using css around the animation variable reference but then I get the V4 error.

Any suggestions to get this to render? I can do it with simple css on click, but it definitely doesn't look as clean and I'd like to know how to use animations in the future.

Thanks!

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled, { keyframes, css } from "styled-components";

type LastUpdatedProps = {
  greenFlash?: boolean | undefined
};

const fillGreen = keyframes`
        from { 
            background-color: "none";
            color: "none";
            width: 100%;
            font-size: "1rem";
        }
        25%{
            font-size: '1.2rem';
        
        }

        50% {
            background-color: "#007e00";
            color: "#007e00";
            width: 80%;
            font-size: "1.4rem";
            
        }
        75%{
            font-size: '1.2rem';
        }
        100% {
            background-color: "none";
            color: "none";
            width: 100%;
            font-size: "1rem";
    }
`;

const LastUpdated =
  styled.div <LastUpdatedProps>`
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontColor};
    margin-left: 0.4rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: "100%";
    font-size: "1rem";
    animation: ${(props) =>
      props.greenFlash
        ? css`
            ${fillGreen}
          `
        : ""};
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: linear;
`;

const Example: React.FC = ({}) => {
  const [greenFlash, setGreenFlash] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setGreenFlash(!greenFlash)}> </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is `LastUpdated` used and is the prop `greenFlash` passed to it?

Comment: Last Updated is just returned in the render and greenFlash is passed as props to it, yes.

`<LastUpdated>Last updated:</LastUpdated>`

`<LastUpdated greenFlash={greenFlash}>` 

        `{lastUpdated === "Loading.." ? getLastUpdate() : lastUpdated}`

`</LastUpdated>`